# How do I plot a graph of previously grouped data?

Tags: python, graph, seaborn

I have a dataframe where I have grouped and summed the data. However, I cannot seem to get it to graph properly.

(Part of) the dataframe:

`({'Order':['AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC'], 'Charge': [1.50,2.50,3.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,1.00,2.50,3.50]})`

I have used:

`df_test.groupby('Order')['Charge'].sum()`

to get:

`({'Order':['AA','BB','CC'], 'Charge': [7.00,6.00,7.00]})`

I then used:
`df_test.groupby('Order')['Charge'].sum().value_counts()`

to get:

`({'Charge': [7.00,6.00],'Count': [2,1]})`

When I try to plot a graph, I get the single values in the dataframe instead of the count of the summed value:

```
sns.countplot(data=df_test, x="Charge", palette="inferno")
```

How do I plot a graph showing the output of:

`df_test.groupby('Order')['Charge'].sum().value_counts()`?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

LT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your just need to add `.reset_index()` to your grouped dataframe and let seaborn's `countplot()` do the equivalent of `value_counts()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
data= {
    'Order':['AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC'],
    'Charge': [1.50,2.50,3.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,1.00,2.50,3.50]
})

count_df = df.groupby('Order')['Charge'].sum().reset_index()
```

The `count_df` will look like so:

```
    Order   Charge
0   AA      7.0
1   BB      6.0
2   CC      7.0
```

The code to generate the plot doesn't change and produces a graph like this:[image]

Comment: Great! Don't [forget](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark the answer as accepted.